# Is 2005 Golf gen IV or V?

Tags: vw, golf

Sometimes I see 2005 golfs described as MK IV, and sometimes as Mk V. Which is which? Can a 2005 Golf be either Mk IV or k V?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkswagen_Golf#Fifth_generation_(MK5/A5,_Typ_1K;_(2003%E2%80%932008)), The Mk5 was released in 2003, but the Mk4 continued in production in some markets until at least 2010 - so the answer is that it depends where you are...

Comment: I wrote an answer based on Wiki, then realized it was a little more complicated than I thought.